# Swift Tableview search result selected cell checkmark not persisting

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am loading data from my `JSON` with Codable into `UITableView`. Here, Tableview I implemented multiple cell selection checkmark option. I am using two array for normal data load and other one for filter array data. Here, Every single selection I am appending `isSelected` for checkmark persistant. Normal data load with checkmark cell selection working fine. But whenever I  tried to search and selected checkmark showing in search result but after clear the search data I cant able to see search selected checkmark into tableview.

I am using two array one for `normal` data load an another one for tableview `search` data. How to achieve this `checkmark` availability after search clear.

**My Code**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return searching ? filteredData.count : membersData.count
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:listCustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! listCustomCell
    let textForRow = searching ? filteredData[indexPath.row] : membersData[indexPath.row]
       cell.empName.text = textForRow.firstname
       cell.designationLabel.text = textForRow.designation
       return cell
}

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
            if  searching == false {
                membersData[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
            } else {
                filteredData[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
            }
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
            let selectedAreas = membersData.filter{$0.isSelected}
            let selectedfilterAreas = filteredData.filter{$0.isSelected}
            print("\(selectedAreas)")
            print("\(selectedfilterAreas)")
        }
```

Comment: do add your cellForRowAt Function, that's the main culprit, probably dequeing cell is the problem!

Comment: @ShivamGaur I updated my question. Could you please check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your logic is incorrect the thing is you are not updating the datasource which is 
showing the data when the searching is off.
Solution is when you are toggling the filtered array , at that time do toggle the original datasource array that is your membersData also!!.
There must be a key differentiating the employees , so when you select a employee while searching at that time upadte the membersData isSelected for that employee.

TOO Many Edits :p
    eq - // Im assuming emp_id be a unique key . also membersData is mutable

```
CODE -
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        if  searching == false {
            membersData[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
        } else {
            filteredData[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
            let empId = filterdData[indexPath.row].emp_id
            for (index,obj) in membersData.enumerated() {
             membersData[index].isSelected = obj.emp_id == empId ? filteredData[indexPath.row].isSelected : obj.isSelected
             }
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
        let selectedAreas = membersData.filter{$0.isSelected}
        let selectedfilterAreas = filteredData.filter{$0.isSelected}
        print("\(selectedAreas)")
        print("\(selectedfilterAreas)")
    }
```

Comment: Thank you I will try and update you here. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What I need to provide here. `[YourObjectType]` ?

Comment: I am getting error on `Cannot assign to property: 'obj' is a 'let' constant` and `Cannot convert value of type '()' to closure result type '[TeamListData]'` line at `let userID = filteredData[indexPath.row].userid
            membersData.map { (obj) -> [TeamListData] in
             obj.isSelected = obj.userid == userID ? filteredData[indexPath.row].isSelected : obj.isSelected
             }`

Comment: Hi buddy Could you please tell me why that error occurring?

Comment: Great Man. Working Charm. Thank you so much. I learned lot from your code. Super :)